# Return a composite type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, pattern-matching, plpgsql

I extract start value and end value from an input string and store them it in local variables which I need to return as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.getweeks_data(paramweek character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF test.weekly_data_type AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
     v_start_date date;
     v_end_date date;
     r test.weekly_data_type%rowtype;

BEGIN

    v_start_date := to_date(substring( paramweek, '^...........'), 'DD Mon YYYY');
    v_end_date := to_date(substring( paramweek, '...........$'),'DD Mon YYYY'); 

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

My type is defined as

```
CREATE TYPE test.weekly_data_type AS
   (week_start_date date,
    week_end_date date
    );
```

Please suggest a suitable way to return `v_start_date` and `v_end_date`.

Comment: This has no *array* anywhere. I took the liberty and adjusted the title to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r.week_start_date := v_start_date;
r.week_end_data := v_end_date;
RETURN NEXT r;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function can (and should) be improved in multiple places:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getweeks_data(paramweek text
                                       , OUT week_start_date date
                                       , OUT week_end_date date) AS
$func$
SELECT to_date(left (paramweek, 11), 'DD Mon YYYY')
     , to_date(right(paramweek, 11), 'DD Mon YYYY')
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
```

- Do not use `SETOF`, you only return a single row.
  You *could* use your custom composite type, but I suggest to simplify with [`OUT` parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) as demonstrated.
- Make the function `IMMUTABLE`, not `VOLATILE`. Better performance for repeated calls.
- You don't need plpgsql at all. A simple SQL function does the job. Can be "inlined" in big queries, better performance for repeated calls.
- Use `left()` and `right()` instead of regular expression. Simpler, shorter, faster.